# How to implement Conflation for probability distribution in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, distribution

I looked online for performing the combining several continuous probability distributions into one continuous probability distribution. This method is called Conflation, the method can be found in the following article: [An Optimal Method for Consolidating Data from Different Experiments](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1005/1005.4978.pdf). In this article, I found out that it was better to perform Conflation instead of averaging to combine distributions.

From what I understood from the article is that equation performs by multiplying each probability density values from several probability distributions divided by the integration of the product of each probability density value from several probability distributions for continuous distribution while for the discrete distribution it is done by multiplying each probability density value from several probability distributions divided by the summation of each probability density value from several probability distributions. (Details can be found on page 5 of the article) [image]
[image]

Say I have around 4 lists from, for example, 4 norm distributions, for example,

```
list_1 = [5, 8, 6, 2, 1]
list_2 = [2, 6, 1, 3, 8]
list_3 = [1, 9, 2, 7, 5]
list_4 = [3, 2, 4, 1, 6]
```

and implementing the Conflation the result list becomes,

```
Con_list = [2.73, 34.56, 3.69, 3.23, 12]
```

(Correct me if I am wrong)

how is it possible to implement both equations in the photo into python to get the Conflation of inputted PDF distribution?

I found stackflow question before regarding averaging list and the code was the following,

```
def average(l):
    llen = len(l)
    def divide(x):
        return x / llen
    # return map(divide, map(sum, zip(*l)))
    return map(divide, map(sum, zip(l)))
```

I have been trying to recode this function to follow the equation above but I can't find a way to get conflated pdf for a continuous distribution.

**Edit 1:**

Based on the answer from *@Josh Purtell*, I rewrote the code, however, I keep on getting the following error message:

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/c903d99d60f20c3b/main.py", line 72, in <module>
    graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)
  File "/tmp/sessions/c903d99d60f20c3b/main.py", line 58, in conflate_pdf
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 341, in quad
    points)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 448, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Code:

```
def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
    prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
    for pdf in pdfs:
        prod=prod*pdf
    return prod

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
    return prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain, dist_1)
plt.plot(domain, dist_2)
plt.plot(domain, dist_3)
plt.plot(domain, dist_4)
plt.plot(domain, dist_5)
plt.plot(domain,graph)
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.show()
```

From the code, what causes this error?

**Edit 2:**

I managed to rewrite the code to look into lists of distribution instead of getting the pdf in the product function in **Edit 1**, but still, I keep on having the same error in **Edit 1**.

Code:

```
def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
    prod=np.ones(np.array(pdfs)[0].shape)
    for pdf in pdfs:
        print(prod)
        for c,y in enumerate(pdf):
            prod[c]=prod[c]*y
        print('final:', prod)
    return prod

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
    print('Denom: ',denom)
    print('product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print(conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)


plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm')
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.show()
```

**Edit 3:**

I tried to run the following code (based on an answer from *@Josh Purtell*), but, I keep on getting one variable it gets the whole array after product function and it produces the same error message regarding the size-1 array. See the following code with a portion of the output:

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for dist in dists:
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pd

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
print('distribution list: \n', dists)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

Here is a small portion of the output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.41991991e-32 2.72804284e-32 ... 6.41980576e-15
 5.92770938e-15 5.47278628e-15]
final: [4.75178372e-48 5.66328097e-48 6.74864868e-48 ... 7.03075979e-21
 6.27970218e-21 5.60806584e-21]
final: [2.80912097e-61 3.51131870e-61 4.38823989e-61 ... 1.32670185e-26
 1.14952951e-26 9.95834610e-27]
final: [1.51005552e-81 2.03116529e-81 2.73144352e-81 ... 1.76466623e-34
 1.46198598e-34 1.21092834e-34]
final: [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
Input product pdf:  [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
Incoming Array: 1
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.41991991e-32 2.72804284e-32 ... 6.41980576e-15
 5.92770938e-15 5.47278628e-15]
final: [4.75178372e-48 5.66328097e-48 6.74864868e-48 ... 7.03075979e-21
 6.27970218e-21 5.60806584e-21]
final: [2.80912097e-61 3.51131870e-61 4.38823989e-61 ... 1.32670185e-26
 1.14952951e-26 9.95834610e-27]
final: [1.51005552e-81 2.03116529e-81 2.73144352e-81 ... 1.76466623e-34
 1.46198598e-34 1.21092834e-34]
final: [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
```

I managed to look into the code to implement the same method in **Edit 3**, I edited the code where it gets the first variables from each distribution however, for the rest of the loop it keeps on printing the same values, it does not go to the next values in the lists and Conflated distribution is a single variable. See the following code with a portion of the output:

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for c,dist in enumerate(dists):
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist[c]
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
print('distribution list: \n', dists)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

A portion of the output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Denom:  3.95931575736075e-96
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Conflated PDF:  0.049999999999999996
```

**Edit 4:**

I implemented the following code and it seems to work, also, I managed to sort out the problem with `quad` it seems if I changed the `quad` into `fixed_quad` and normalise the pdf list. I will get the same result. Here is the following code:

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer, normalize, StandardScaler
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps, quad_vec, nquad, cumulative_trapezoid
from scipy.integrate import romberg, trapezoid, simpson, romb
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad, quadrature, quad_explain
from scipy import stats
import time

def user_prod_pdf(x,dists):
p_list=[]
p_pdf=1
print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
for dist in dists:
print('Incoming Distribution Array:', dist.pdf(x))
p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
p_list.append(p_pdf)
print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
return p_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
print('Input product pdf: ', user_prod_pdf(x,dists))
denom = quad(user_prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
print('Denom: ', denom)
conflated_pdf=user_prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
return conflated_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf_2(pdfs):
"""
Compute conflation of given pdfs.

[ARGS]
- pdfs: PDFs numpy array of shape (n, x)
where n is the number of PDFs
and x is the variable space.

[RETURN]
A 1d-array of normalized conflated PDF.
"""
# conflate
conflation = np.array(pdfs).prod(axis=0)
# normalize
conflation /= conflation.sum()
return conflation

def my_product_pdf(x,dists):
p_list=[]
p_pdf=1
print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
list_full_size=np.array(dists).shape
print('Full list size: ', list_full_size)
print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])
for x in range(list_full_size[1]):
p_pdf=1
for y in range(list_full_size[0]):
p_pdf=float(p_pdf)*dists[y][x]
print('Product value: ', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
p_list.append(p_pdf)
print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
# return p_pdf
return p_list
# return np.array(p_list)

def my_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
print('\n')
# print('product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
print('product pdf: ', my_product_pdf(x,dists))
denom = fixed_quad(my_product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,), n=1)[0]
print('Denom: ', denom)
# conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
conflated_pdf=my_product_pdf(x,dists)/denom
# conflated_pdf=[i / j for i,j in zip(my_product_pdf(x,dists), denom)]
print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

# dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
# dist_2 = st.norm(2.5,1.5)
# dist_3 = st.norm(2.2,1.6)
# dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
# dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
# dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
# dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
# dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
# dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm(4,2)
dist_3 = st.norm(7,4)
dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 4,2)
dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 7,4)
dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

# User:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# User 2:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF 2")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf_2(dists)
print('Final User Conflated PDF 2 : ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# My Code:
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("My Conflated PDF Code")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
my_graph=my_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', my_graph)

my_graph /= np.array(my_graph).sum()

# my_graph = inverse_normalise(my_graph)

plt.plot(domain, my_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Conflated PDF:
print('User Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)
print('My Conflated PDF: ', np.array(my_graph))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question here, I understand that I would need to normalise the PDF lists. But, say I did not normalise the PDF, how can I modify my conflation code to get the following plot?

[image]

To get the plot above and my conflated code:

```
# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()
# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()
```

My conflated code plot with no normalisation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: there's a good chance I'm misunderstanding either you or the paper authors, in which case please suggest an edit to this answer.

Here is a trivial, not-especially-performant implementation of what I think conflation might look like

```
##define pdfs for discrete RV X = {1,2,3,4}
import numpy as np

def mult_list(pdfs):
    prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
    for pdf in pdfs:
        prod=prod*pdf
    return prod

def conflate(pdfs):
    return mult_list(pdfs)/sum(mult_list(pdfs))

pdf_1=np.array([.25,.25,.25,.25])
pdf_2=np.array([.33,.33,.33,.00])
pdf_3=np.array([.25,.12,.13,.50])

print(conflate([pdf_1,pdf_2,pdf_3]))
```

which yields the resulting conflated pdf

```
>>> [0.5  0.24 0.26 0.  ]
```

which passes a cursory sniff test.

On the continuous side of things, the above translates to

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    for dist in dists:
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
    return prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom

dists=[stats.norm(2,1),stats.norm(4,2)]
lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain,graph)
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.show()
plt.savefig("conflatedpdf.png")
```

which gives [image: conflatedpdf]

As you can see, the distribution is not bimodal, just as one would hope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just for me to understand your code, so you will be multiplying the value from each list by one and then for multiplication part, it is done at the numerator and denominator will look sum operator. also, what if it is a continuous distribution?

Comment: @WDpad159 just added my approach for continuous distributions

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the previous comment is my explanation to the code is right?

Comment: Here is a quote from the paper: "For discrete input distributions, the analogous definition of conflation is the normalized product of the probability mass functions". In the code, I find the product of the pmfs (discrete analogue of pdf, my code naming admittedly elides this distinction) for each element in the RV image space, and then normalize that product with the sum of all such products (so that it adds to one). The reason I initialize the product with 1 is so the for loop is symmetric; it's like initializing a sum with 0.

Comment: the code works fine but if I used pdfs as a list, I keep on getting error in the code. See the edited question.

Comment: I tried to rewrite the code but still, I get the error regarding size-1 arrays. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you have a look at my code **Edit 3** and see what could be the reason why I can get the same output as yours?

Comment: I made some modifications to my code, could you have a look at **Edit 4**?