# How to fix error regarding size-1 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scipy

I was looking into a problem regarding combining several continuous probability distributions into one continuous probability distribution using an equation from a method called Conflation (Conflation equation can be found at the following link: [Conflation method question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346110/how-to-implement-conflation-for-probability-distribution-in-python). When I ran the code, I got an error message regarding size-1 arrays. Here is my code with the error message:

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/c903d99d60f20c3b/main.py", line 72, in <module>
    graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)
  File "/tmp/sessions/c903d99d60f20c3b/main.py", line 58, in conflate_pdf
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 341, in quad
    points)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 448, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Code:

```
def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
    prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
    for pdf in pdfs:
        prod=prod*pdf
    return prod

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
    return prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain, dist_1)
plt.plot(domain, dist_2)
plt.plot(domain, dist_3)
plt.plot(domain, dist_4)
plt.plot(domain, dist_5)
plt.plot(domain,graph)
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.show()
```

From the code, what causes this error message?

**Edit 1:**

I modified the code and made some corrections, but still, I keep on getting the same error message. See below the following code and error message from the code:

Code:

```
def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    prod=np.ones(np.array(dists)[0].shape)
    for dist in dists:
        print(prod)
        for c,y in enumerate(dist):
            prod[c]=prod[c]*y
        print('final:', prod)
    return prod

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, dists)[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    print('product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm')
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.show()
```

Traceback Message locations:

*line 341:*

```
if weight is None:
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,points)
```

*line 448:*

```
def _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points):
    infbounds = 0
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
        pass   # standard integration
    elif (b == Inf and a != -Inf):
        infbounds = 1
        bound = a
    elif (b == Inf and a == -Inf):
        infbounds = 2
        bound = 0     # ignored
    elif (b != Inf and a == -Inf):
        infbounds = -1
        bound = b
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Infinity comparisons don't work for you.")

    if points is None:
        if infbounds == 0:
            return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
        else:
            return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    else:
        if infbounds != 0:
            raise ValueError("Infinity inputs cannot be used with break points.")
        else:
            #Duplicates force function evaluation at singular points
            the_points = numpy.unique(points)
            the_points = the_points[a < the_points]
            the_points = the_points[the_points < b]
            the_points = numpy.concatenate((the_points, (0., 0.)))
            return _quadpack._qagpe(func,a,b,the_points,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
```

**Edit 2:**

After discussion with *@hpaulj*, it seems the problem is with the product function. From the link [Conflation method question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346110/how-to-implement-conflation-for-probability-distribution-in-python), the code was able to run without the error with of size-1 array. Here is the code with further details:

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for dist in dists:
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)
dists=[stats.norm(2,1), stats.norm(2.5,1.5), stats.norm(2.2,1.6), stats.norm(2.4,1.3), stats.norm(2.7,1.5)]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

graph=conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is a small portion of the output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: 0.15352177537004433
final: 0.034348669264845304
final: 0.006519131844904635
final: 0.0015040030811035296
final: 0.0003607258742065213
Incoming Array: 1
final: 0.042345986284209325
final: 0.006294747321619583
final: 0.0007651214249593444
final: 9.805307029794648e-05
final: 1.668121592516301e-05
Denom:  0.0029066671327537714
Incoming Array: 1
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.41991991e-32 2.72804284e-32 ... 6.41980576e-15
 5.92770938e-15 5.47278628e-15]
final: [4.75178372e-48 5.66328097e-48 6.74864868e-48 ... 7.03075979e-21
 6.27970218e-21 5.60806584e-21]
final: [2.80912097e-61 3.51131870e-61 4.38823989e-61 ... 1.32670185e-26
 1.14952951e-26 9.95834610e-27]
final: [1.51005552e-81 2.03116529e-81 2.73144352e-81 ... 1.76466623e-34
 1.46198598e-34 1.21092834e-34]
final: [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
Conflated PDF:  [3.75264162e-95 5.34063998e-95 7.59844666e-95 ... 1.28014389e-37
 1.02682689e-37 8.23400219e-38]
```

Plot:

[image]

The way I see it, it takes each density value from one and multiplies it with other distributions. However, if I look at my case, instead of getting one variable it gets the whole array after product function and it produces the same error regarding the size-1 array. See the following code with a portion of the output:

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for dist in dists:
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pd

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
print('distribution list: \n', dists)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

Here is a small portion of the output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.41991991e-32 2.72804284e-32 ... 6.41980576e-15
 5.92770938e-15 5.47278628e-15]
final: [4.75178372e-48 5.66328097e-48 6.74864868e-48 ... 7.03075979e-21
 6.27970218e-21 5.60806584e-21]
final: [2.80912097e-61 3.51131870e-61 4.38823989e-61 ... 1.32670185e-26
 1.14952951e-26 9.95834610e-27]
final: [1.51005552e-81 2.03116529e-81 2.73144352e-81 ... 1.76466623e-34
 1.46198598e-34 1.21092834e-34]
final: [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
Input product pdf:  [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
Incoming Array: 1
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.41991991e-32 2.72804284e-32 ... 6.41980576e-15
 5.92770938e-15 5.47278628e-15]
final: [4.75178372e-48 5.66328097e-48 6.74864868e-48 ... 7.03075979e-21
 6.27970218e-21 5.60806584e-21]
final: [2.80912097e-61 3.51131870e-61 4.38823989e-61 ... 1.32670185e-26
 1.14952951e-26 9.95834610e-27]
final: [1.51005552e-81 2.03116529e-81 2.73144352e-81 ... 1.76466623e-34
 1.46198598e-34 1.21092834e-34]
final: [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
```

**Edit 3:**

I managed to look into the code to implement the same method in ***Edit 2***, I edited the code where it gets the first variables from each distribution however, for the rest of the loop it keeps on printing the same values, it does not go to the next values in the lists and Conflated distribution is a single variable. See the following code with a portion of the output:

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for c,dist in enumerate(dists):
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist[c]
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
print('distribution list: \n', dists)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

A portion of the output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Denom:  3.95931575736075e-96
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Conflated PDF:  0.049999999999999996
```

**Edit 3:**

I implemented the following code and it seems to work, also, I managed to sort out the problem with `quad` it seems if I changed the `quad` into `fixed_quad` and normalise the pdf list. I will get the same result. Here is the following code:

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer, normalize, StandardScaler
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps, quad_vec, nquad, cumulative_trapezoid
from scipy.integrate import romberg, trapezoid, simpson, romb
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad, quadrature, quad_explain
from scipy import stats
import time

def user_prod_pdf(x,dists):
p_list=[]
p_pdf=1
print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
for dist in dists:
print('Incoming Distribution Array:', dist.pdf(x))
p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
p_list.append(p_pdf)
print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
return p_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
print('Input product pdf: ', user_prod_pdf(x,dists))
denom = quad(user_prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
print('Denom: ', denom)
conflated_pdf=user_prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
return conflated_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf_2(pdfs):
"""
Compute conflation of given pdfs.

[ARGS]
- pdfs: PDFs numpy array of shape (n, x)
where n is the number of PDFs
and x is the variable space.

[RETURN]
A 1d-array of normalized conflated PDF.
"""
# conflate
conflation = np.array(pdfs).prod(axis=0)
# normalize
conflation /= conflation.sum()
return conflation

def my_product_pdf(x,dists):
p_list=[]
p_pdf=1
print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
list_full_size=np.array(dists).shape
print('Full list size: ', list_full_size)
print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])
for x in range(list_full_size[1]):
p_pdf=1
for y in range(list_full_size[0]):
p_pdf=float(p_pdf)*dists[y][x]
print('Product value: ', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
p_list.append(p_pdf)
print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
# return p_pdf
return p_list
# return np.array(p_list)

def my_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
print('\n')
# print('product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
print('product pdf: ', my_product_pdf(x,dists))
denom = fixed_quad(my_product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,), n=1)[0]
print('Denom: ', denom)
# conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
conflated_pdf=my_product_pdf(x,dists)/denom
# conflated_pdf=[i / j for i,j in zip(my_product_pdf(x,dists), denom)]
print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

# dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
# dist_2 = st.norm(2.5,1.5)
# dist_3 = st.norm(2.2,1.6)
# dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
# dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
# dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
# dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
# dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
# dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm(4,2)
dist_3 = st.norm(7,4)
dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 4,2)
dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 7,4)
dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

# User:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# User 2:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF 2")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf_2(dists)
print('Final User Conflated PDF 2 : ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# My Code:
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("My Conflated PDF Code")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
my_graph=my_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', my_graph)

my_graph /= np.array(my_graph).sum()

# my_graph = inverse_normalise(my_graph)

plt.plot(domain, my_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Conflated PDF:
print('User Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)
print('My Conflated PDF: ', np.array(my_graph))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question here, I understand that I would need to normalise the PDF lists. But, say I did not normalise the PDF, how can I modify my conflation code to get the following plot?

[image]

To get the plot above and my conflated code:

```
# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()
# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()
```

My conflated code plot with no normalisation:

[image]

Comment: Do a bit of research in the scipy docs regarding the syntax (accepted arguments, etc.) on this line: `denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]`

Comment: You are passing an array (with more than 1 value) to a function that expects a scalar, a single number.  Examine the traceback and determine which argument is wrong!

Comment: @S3DEV I understand how this line works but in the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346110/how-to-implement-conflation-for-probability-distribution-in-python) the answer showed that it was possible to implement integration. I tried to modify the code in where I get several distributions lists (maybe not norm distribution) and do the same method but I keep on getting the same error.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand how this line works but in the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346110/how-to-implement-conflation-for-probability-distribution-in-python) the answer showed that it was possible to implement integration. I tried to modify the code in where I get several distributions lists (maybe not norm distribution) and do the same method but I keep on getting the same error.

Comment: where oh where does this little error occur?  We can't help you without the traceback.  I can't run code like this in my head!

Comment: @hpaulj is this what you mean? (Check edit question)

Comment: @hpaulj I've seen you around; I'm pretty sure you can

Comment: No, I still have no idea what line and function call has the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj I am really sorry but I am confused and don't know how to simplify the question. Here is the function that I am using from scipy (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.1/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L49-L442)

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the traceback at the head of the question.  Maybe I was focused on the code, or expected the traceback near the end.  Or I expected a longer one. You are only passing 4 arguments to `quad`: `prod_pdf, lb, ub, dists`, a function, 2 scalars (or at least they should be), and `args` tuple.  Passing `args=(dists,)` might help, but I don't see how that would raise the size-1 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `ipython` session, I copied your code.  On my earlier reads it didn't look like it was complete and runnable.  But with a couple of imports it does run and produce your error:

```
In [1]: from scipy.integrate import quad
In [2]: from scipy import stats
In [3]: def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
   ...:     prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
   ...:     for pdf in pdfs:
   ...:         prod=prod*pdf
   ...:     return prod
   ...: 
   ...: def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
   ...:     denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
   ...:     return prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
   ...: 
   ...: lb=-10
   ...: ub=10
   ...: domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)
   ...: 
   ...: dist_1 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
   ...: dist_2 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
   ...: dist_3 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
   ...: dist_4 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
   ...: dist_5 = stats.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)
   ...: 
   ...: dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
   ...: graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)
   ...:
```

The traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-a55a08f59f08>", line 22, in <module>
    graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)
  File "<ipython-input-3-a55a08f59f08>", line 8, in conflate_pdf
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists))[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The error is in compiled code, so doesn't give further information.  So we have to resort to examining inputs and outputs.

My first thought there was a problem with arguments to `quad`.  So to be sure I threw in some prints.

```
In [5]: def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
   ...:     prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
   ...:     for pdf in pdfs:
   ...:         prod=prod*pdf
   ...:     return prod
   ...: 
   ...: def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
   ...:     print(lb, ub, dists)
   ...:     denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
   ...:     return prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
   ...: 

 ....
-10 10 [array([2.14638374e-32, 2.41991991e-32, 2.72804284e-32, ...,
       6.41980576e-15, 5.92770938e-15, 5.47278628e-15]), .
```

upper and lower bounds look ok, `dists` is a list.  In a simpler case I tested arrays for the bounds and got different errors.

So does `prod_pdf` get called?

```
In [6]: def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
   ...:     print(x, pdfs)
   ...:     prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
   ...:     for pdf in pdfs:
   ...:         prod=prod*pdf
   ...:     return prod
   ...: 
   ....

0.0 [array([2.14638374e-32, 2.41991991e-32, 2.72804284e-32, ...,
       6.41980576e-15, 5.92770938e-15, 5.47278628e-15]), ....
```

So `prod_pdf` is called, with 0 and the dists list; expected values.

So what is `prod` that's being returned?

```
In [8]: def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
   ...:     prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
   ...:     for pdf in pdfs:
   ...:         prod=prod*pdf
   ...:     print(prod)
   ...:     return prod
   ...
[1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
```

What's its shape?

```
In [9]: def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
   ...:     prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
   ...:     for pdf in pdfs:
   ...:         prod=prod*pdf
   ...:     print(prod.shape)
   ...:     return prod
   ...: 
....
(2000,)
```

**Whoops!**  `quad` integrates a scalar function.  `prod_pdf` is supposed to return a scalar, a single number, not 2000 values.  That's the error `_quadpack._qagse` is complaining about.  The problem isn't the inputs to `quad`, but the value returned by your function.

Now that I know what to look for, the error is obvious.

If we artificially truncate it to 1 value, the `quad` runs without error.

```
In [10]: def prod_pdf(x,pdfs):
    ...:     prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])
    ...:     for pdf in pdfs:
    ...:         prod=prod*pdf
    ...:     print(prod.shape)
    ...:     return prod[0]
```

I'm leaving in all those debugging steps (with a lot of editing) so you see the steps I had to go through.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I modified my code to EDIT 1. But, I keep on getting the same error. Furthermore, if you look at the answer to the question in the following link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346110/how-to-implement-conflation-for-probability-distribution-in-python) The answer was able to integrate and produce a plot of conflated PDF, I am just trying to get to that step but using lists instead of getting pdf in function. Have a look at the link and you will understand what I mean in this comment

Comment: I haven't looked at your bigger problem or that link.  My focus was on the title error - the size-1 issue.  `quad` does not work if the function returns multiple values.  In the `prod_pdf` I tested, it returned an array the same size as one of your `dists`, (2000,).  That's wrong.  The purpose of `quad` is to perform a 1d integral, returning just **one** float number.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I went through the function in Scipy to further understand it and its variables. The link that I am mentioning didn't produce this error. I thought if you had a look at it, it might help you (get an idea where I made the mistake in my code so that it can do similar to the users' answer and what could be missing in my code) and me (to get a further understanding of the reason why this error occurs and what is different in my code and users code) Could you please have a look?

Comment: The linked question got the same error.  The answer uses a different `prod_pdf`, one that returns a single number.  As long as you return `prod=np.ones(pdfs[0].shape[0])` or something the same size, you will get this `size-1` error.  The `denom=quad(...)` line is supposed to produce **one** value, not 2000.

Comment: Okay, so I think the problem here is the prod_pdf function is that it returns the array instead of a single variable which causes this problem. I looked at his code and run it separately, I managed to find that it was printing out the single variable and manage to get one variable for the denominator. I tried to tweak my code to do that But instead, it keeps on getting a product of whole array. See the edited question **Edit 2**.