# How to implement Quad to a list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scipy

I have been going through the concept of applying a method called Conflation which looks into combining several distributions together. I asked the question in the following link: [How to implement Conflation for probability distribution in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346110/how-to-implement-conflation-for-probability-distribution-in-python), where this question is answered with the following code:

```
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    for dist in dists:
        print('Incoming Array:', dist.pdf(x))
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return print('Product: ', p_pdf), p_pdf
    
def product_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    for dist in dists:
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists)[1])
    denom = quad(product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=product_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[stats.norm(2,1), stats.norm(2.5,1.5), stats.norm(2.2,1.6), stats.norm(2.4,1.3), stats.norm(2.7,1.5)]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The area that I am concentrating on is the continuous distribution part where it uses the equation with integration in the denominator. I understand that the error in the code was due to a 1-size array error when using integration. So, I thought that the input to the quad is to use a single integer and I tried to modify the code to do the same result as the above code. The code can be found below:

```
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def product_pdf(x,dists):
    p_list=[]
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    list_full_size=np.array(dists).shape
    print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])
    for x in range(list_full_size[1]):
        p_pdf=1
        for y in range(list_full_size[0]):
            p_pdf=p_pdf*dists[y][x]
            # print('Incoming Distribution Array:', dist)
            print('Product value: ', p_pdf)
        print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
        p_list.append(p_pdf)
    print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
    print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
    # return p_pdf
    return p_list
    # return np.array(p_list)

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    denom_list=[]
    # time.sleep(500)
    print('\n')
    print('product pdf: ', product_pdf(x,dists))
    prod=product_pdf(x,dists)
    prod_size=np.array(prod).shape[0]
    print('Product Size: ', prod_size)
    # time.sleep(20)
    for i in range(prod_size):
        denom = quad(product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(prod[i],))[0]
        denom_list.append(denom)
        print('Denom: ', denom)
    print('Denominator list: ', denom_list)
    # time.sleep(20)
    # conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    conflated_pdf=product_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 4,2)
dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 7,4)
dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1))
# dist_2 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5))
# dist_3 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6))
# dist_4 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3))
# dist_5 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm(4,2)
dist_3 = st.norm(7,4)
dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

# dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

When I ran the code, I got the following output:

```
print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I know that the error is related to the size of the list, but, how can I modify the code to be able to produce the same result and plot to the first code?

**Edit 1:**

I looked into the code again and managed to find that if I replaced the `quad` with `fixed_quad`, it will be able to run the code with no error. However, the plot is not the same as the `user_conflation_pdf` method. Here is the code of my approach,

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer, normalize, StandardScaler
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps, quad_vec, nquad, cumulative_trapezoid
from scipy.integrate import romberg, trapezoid, simpson, romb
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad, quadrature, quad_explain
from scipy import stats
import time

def user_prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_list=[]
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for dist in dists:
        print('Incoming Distribution Array:', dist.pdf(x))
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
        print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
        p_list.append(p_pdf)
    print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
    print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
    return p_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', user_prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(user_prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=user_prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

def my_product_pdf(x,dists):
    p_list=[]
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    list_full_size=np.array(dists).shape
    print('Full list size: ', list_full_size)
    print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])
    for x in range(list_full_size[1]):
        p_pdf=1
        for y in range(list_full_size[0]):
            p_pdf=float(p_pdf)*dists[y][x]
            print('Product value: ', p_pdf)
        print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
        p_list.append(p_pdf)
    print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
    print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
    # return p_pdf
    return p_list
    # return np.array(p_list)
    
def my_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    conflated_pdf_list=[]
    num=my_product_pdf(x,dists)
    print('\n')
    # print('product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    print('product pdf: ', my_product_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = fixed_quad(my_product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,), n=1)[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    # conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    # conflated_pdf=my_product_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    # conflated_pdf=[i / j for i,j in zip(my_product_pdf(x,dists), denom)]
    for i in np.arange(np.array(num).shape[0]):
        conflated_pdf = num[i] / denom
        conflated_pdf_list.append(conflated_pdf)
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf_list)
    return conflated_pdf_list

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

# dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
# dist_2 = st.norm(2.5,1.5)
# dist_3 = st.norm(2.2,1.6)
# dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
# dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
# dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
# dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
# dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
# dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm(4,2)
dist_3 = st.norm(7,4)
dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 4,2)
dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 7,4)
dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

# User:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# My Code:
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("My Conflated PDF Code")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
my_graph=my_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', my_graph)

# my_graph /= np.array(my_graph).sum()

# my_graph = inverse_normalise(my_graph)

plt.plot(domain, my_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Conflated PDF:
print('User Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)
print('My Conflated PDF: ', my_graph)
```

Here is the following output:

[image]

[image]

But, if I normalise the pdf list, output plots are the same. Here is what needs to be changed to normalise the list,

```
user_graph /= user_graph.sum()
dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

How can I modify my code/functions to be able to obtain this plot?

[image]

Comment: What is the is the size of `list_full_size`?  Do you understand why?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, it comes out to be 2000 length.

Comment: Is that value of the variable, or it's size?   In the code, it is `np.array(dists).shape`; show what is `dists`.  Indexing shape with [0] gives the first dimension.  But if the shape is `()`, it doesn't have a first element.

Comment: @hpaulj its the size of the list and I am trying to using quad to each value of the list

Comment: Assuming the error is at the location I found, `list_full_size` can't be 2000 elements long.  It is the shape of an array, and numpy arrays can have at most 32 dimensions.  But they can have 0 dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried to think about it logically but still, I can't understand why it prints an empty array

Comment: Have you added some test prints?  Even for an experienced programmer, thinking only goes so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230980/discussion-between-wdpad159-and-hpaulj).

Comment: I've answered one of your previous questions, so you know how I go about debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one big complaint - you did not show the full traceback!  By now you should know that it is essential to examine the traceback to see exactly what is causing the problem.

From the little you did show, I deduced that the problem was in:

```
def product_pdf(x,dists):
    p_list=[]
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    list_full_size=np.array(dists).shape
    print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])
    ...
```

Why didn't you highlight that spot?  It took unnecessary time reading the code to find that print line.

That function is called several times in `conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub)`. At least once with a print.  Did that print work?  Your code has a bunch of prints, but you didn't show any of them :(

From

```
dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
graph=conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
```

`dists` is a list of 5 objects.  From that I expect `np.array(dists)` to be at least a 1d array, maybe more if those `pdf` objects are arrays with the same shape.  That means `list_full_size[0]` should work, and match `len(dists)` (i.e. not need to convert the list to an array.

That `array` conversion sort-of helps with the

```
for x in range(list_full_size[1]):
```

though that could just as well be

```
for x in range(len(dists[0])):
```

since the `x` and `y` loops work from `dists`, not `np.array(dists)`.

Anyways, it looks like the `product_pdf(x,dists)` calls should work.

BUT, you also use `product_pdf` in

```
denom = quad(product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(prod[i],))[0]
```

there the `dists` argument is now `prod[i]`, not the original `dists`.

What is `prod`?

```
prod=product_pdf(x,dists)
```

Wait, isn't `product_pdf` supposed to produce **one** number for `quad`?  What are you doing with `prod[i]`, and passing that as the `dist` parameter to `product_pdf`.

`product_pdf` returns `plist`, which  looks like a list of numbers.  So `prod[i]` is one number, and the shape of it, as an array is ().  Hence the error. And now we are back to error I last helped you with - **`quad` requires a scalar valued function.**